# Call all instances' private method with only a call from public static method

Tags: java, android, static-methods, instances, non-static

I am trying to create a library for other app to use.

The library consist of a simple custom view (AutoTranslateTextView) to translate the current text from a language to another language.

The requirement is to allow a single call to AutoTranslateTextView's `public static function translateAllTo(String`) to start translate all instances, please see the code below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class AutoTranslateTextView extends TextView {

    private static final String TAG = AutoTranslateTextView.class.getSimpleName();

    public AutoTranslateTextView(Context context) { this(context, null); }
    public AutoTranslateTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { this(context, attrs, 0); }
    public AutoTranslateTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        if(isInEditMode()) { return; }

        mHandler = new IncomingTranslationRequest(this);
    }

    private static IncomingTranslationRequest mHandler;

    private static class IncomingTranslationRequest extends Handler {

        private WeakReference<AutoTranslateTextView> mHAutoTranslateTextView;

        public IncomingTranslationRequest(AutoTranslateTextView hattv) {
            mHAutoTranslateTextView = new WeakReference<AutoTranslateTextView>(hattv);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            if(msg.what == 1) {
                if(msg.obj != null) {
                    mHAutoTranslateTextView.get().translateTo((String) msg.obj);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "handleMessage(Message), msg.obj is null or not LanguageLocaleCode");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "handleMessage(Message), unhandled what: " + msg.what);
            }
        }
    };

    public static void translateAllTo(String languageCode) {
        if(languageCode == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "translateAllTo(languageCode), parameter is null");
            return;
        }

        if(mHandler == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "translateAllTo(" + languageCode + "), handler is null");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "translateAllTo(" + languageCode + ")");

        mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mHandler, 1, languageCode));
    }

    private void translateTo(String languageCode) {
        String text = (String) getText();

        Log.d(TAG, "translateTo(" + languageCode + "), current text: " + text);

        // --------- Main logic here ----------
    }
}
```

My problem is that when `translateAllTo(languageCode)` is called, only one (the last) instance will execute `translateTo(languageCode)`.

I know the app (not my library) can call `translateTo(languageCode)` for each instance, but the client ask me this requirement to only call 1 public static method to translate all AutoTranslateTextView instances.

Is this possible?

Comment: This requirement is due to in an activity, there are many AutoTranslateTextView in Fragments inside ViewPager.